# Does having blood vessels close to skin increase sensitivity to heat/cold?

Tags: heat, blood-vessels

I seem to have my blood vessels closer to skin than most people. They are clearly visible on my legs, arms, etc, and I get bruises extremelly easily. I must have inherited that from my mom, who now has problems with varicose veins.

I am also sensitive to cold: get cold faster than most people despite being from the north. And extreme heat has been causing me problems as well: get headaches from sauna/hot tubs or from doing physical exercise in the sun. Recently I don't seem to be able to hike a mountain without a headache afterwards even on a moderatelly warm day.

I was wondering, could my sensitivity to cold/warm temperatures be related to my blood vessels being so close to the skin?

Comment: Would you say you are skinny?

Comment: no, always had a normal BMI, previously more on the lower end of normal, nowadays on the higher end

Comment: OK, I was just about to mention that subcutaneous fat can significantly protect someone against cold.

Comment: Your blood vessels are probably in the same place as everyone else's. If they're more visible that's usually due to low body fat as Jan mentioned, or simply having pale skin. The same vessels that are easily visible in someone with pale skin may be invisible in someone with dark skin.

Comment: I do not have an exceptionally pale skin, I would say average, when compared to other people I know. And I get comments about how visible my blood vessels are from people with much paler skin.